# Return and "this". How can i do. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object

```
const john = {
    firstName: "Jhon",
    lastName: "Smith",
    weight: 92 ,
    height: 1.95 ,

    calcBmi: function() {
          this.bmi = this.weight / ( this.height * 2 );
        return this.bmi;
     }
  }
console.log(john.bmi)
```

Output in console its "undefined" can someone explain what i need to do? Its work if i write "console.log(john.calcBmi())" but i want to create a new variable in this object and use after that multiple time

Comment: You never call the `calcBMI` function, so `this.bmi` will never be set

Comment: you have to call the `john.calcBmi()` function then the `bmi` property will initiate, after you can execute `console.log(john.bmi)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use getter like this:

```js
const john = {
    firstName: "Jhon",
    lastName: "Smith",
    weight: 92 ,
    height: 1.95 ,

    get bmi() {
          return this.weight / ( this.height * 2 );
     }
  }
console.log(john.bmi)
```